# Why would docker not cache 'ENV SHELL /bin/bash'?

Tags: docker, caching, build, teamcity

I have a Dockerfile which caches properly when I build on my machine, but never when I try to build in CI (Teamcity).

On my machine:

```
$ docker build --pull --build-arg RUBY_VERSION=2.6.3 -f Dockerfile_QA_Ruby_Base .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/10 : ARG RUBY_VERSION
Step 2/10 : FROM ruby:$RUBY_VERSION
2.6.3: Pulling from library/ruby
Digest: sha256:358f16e92d0f66599103318f7a8528d449b0973fd89e46a1a5c47cec7479f09b
Status: Image is up to date for ruby:2.6.3
 ---> 8fe6e1f7b421
Step 3/10 : ENV SHELL /bin/bash
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 140493c79747
Step 4/10 : SHELL [ "/bin/bash", "-c" ]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f9720b262f27

... and so on.
```

But on the agent, although it starts from the same base as my laptop, the very first command `ENV SHELL /bin/bash` causes it to diverge!

```
[15:43:41]Starting: docker build -t docker.boo.com/mobile_test_automation/ruby_base:2.6.3_v5947877 --pull --build-arg RUBY_VERSION=2.6.3 -f Dockerfile_QA_Ruby_Base .
[15:43:41]in directory: /local/buildAgent/work/5a9d908b50377da7/infrastructure/docker-qa/ruby_base
[15:43:42]Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
[15:43:42]
[15:43:42]Step 1/10 : ARG RUBY_VERSION
[15:43:42]Step 2/10 : FROM ruby:$RUBY_VERSION
[15:43:43]2.6.3: Pulling from library/ruby
[15:43:43]Digest: sha256:358f16e92d0f66599103318f7a8528d449b0973fd89e46a1a5c47cec7479f09b
[15:43:43]Status: Image is up to date for ruby:2.6.3
[15:43:43] ---> 8fe6e1f7b421
[15:43:43]Step 3/10 : ENV SHELL /bin/bash
[15:43:43] ---> Running in dc64ef81ac64
[15:43:43]Docker event: {"status":"pull","id":"ruby:2.6.3","Type":"image","Action":"pull","Actor":{"ID":"ruby:2.6.3","Attributes":{"name":"ruby"}},"scope":"local","time":1570463023,"timeNano":1570463023696271851}
[15:43:43]Removing intermediate container dc64ef81ac64
[15:43:43] ---> 19f28c3b9ef4
[15:43:43]Create docker info file: /local/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp/.teamcity/docker/build_47/events.json
[15:43:43]Step 4/10 : SHELL [ "/bin/bash", "-c" ]
[15:43:43]Docker event: {"status":"create","id":"dc64ef81ac645a993e6ba97ff61a1eed3846bdbadd04fa2ce12a0276b1498180","from":"sha256:8fe6e1f7b42156aa076eb77e4eb08aa266d33efde513152da23dd37fe898e0c4","Type":"container","Action":"create","Actor":{"ID":"dc64ef81ac645a993e6ba97ff61a1eed3846bdbadd04fa2ce12a0276b1498180","Attributes":{"image":"sha256:8fe6e1f7b42156aa076eb77e4eb08aa266d33efde513152da23dd37fe898e0c4","name":"quirky_kapitsa"}},"scope":"local","time":1570463023,"timeNano":1570463023809349463}
[15:43:43]Docker event: {"status":"destroy","id":"dc64ef81ac645a993e6ba97ff61a1eed3846bdbadd04fa2ce12a0276b1498180","from":"sha256:8fe6e1f7b42156aa076eb77e4eb08aa266d33efde513152da23dd37fe898e0c4","Type":"container","Action":"destroy","Actor":{"ID":"dc64ef81ac645a993e6ba97ff61a1eed3846bdbadd04fa2ce12a0276b1498180","Attributes":{"image":"sha256:8fe6e1f7b42156aa076eb77e4eb08aa266d33efde513152da23dd37fe898e0c4","name":"quirky_kapitsa"}},"scope":"local","time":1570463023,"timeNano":1570463023963402639}
```

Then

```
[15:54:45]Starting: docker build -t docker.boo.com/mobile_test_automation/ruby_base:2.6.3_v5948019 --pull --build-arg RUBY_VERSION=2.6.3 -f Dockerfile_QA_Ruby_Base .
[15:54:45]in directory: /local/buildAgent/work/5a9d908b50377da7/infrastructure/docker-qa/ruby_base
[15:54:45]Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
[15:54:45]
[15:54:46]Step 1/10 : ARG RUBY_VERSION
[15:54:46]Step 2/10 : FROM ruby:$RUBY_VERSION
[15:54:47]2.6.3: Pulling from library/ruby
[15:54:47]Digest: sha256:358f16e92d0f66599103318f7a8528d449b0973fd89e46a1a5c47cec7479f09b
[15:54:47]Status: Image is up to date for ruby:2.6.3
[15:54:47] ---> 8fe6e1f7b421
[15:54:47]Step 3/10 : ENV SHELL /bin/bash
[15:54:47] ---> Running in a048649835ad
[15:54:47]Docker event: {"status":"pull","id":"ruby:2.6.3","Type":"image","Action":"pull","Actor":{"ID":"ruby:2.6.3","Attributes":{"name":"ruby"}},"scope":"local","time":1570463687,"timeNano":1570463687464958018}
[15:54:47]Create docker info file: /local/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp/.teamcity/docker/build_48/events.json
[15:54:47]Docker event: {"status":"create","id":"a048649835add87f2fbbc0342348db72d27d41b20eaad8fc34dc853c17f19add","from":"sha256:8fe6e1f7b42156aa076eb77e4eb08aa266d33efde513152da23dd37fe898e0c4","Type":"container","Action":"create","Actor":{"ID":"a048649835add87f2fbbc0342348db72d27d41b20eaad8fc34dc853c17f19add","Attributes":{"image":"sha256:8fe6e1f7b42156aa076eb77e4eb08aa266d33efde513152da23dd37fe898e0c4","name":"sharp_driscoll"}},"scope":"local","time":1570463687,"timeNano":1570463687588598623}
[15:54:47]Removing intermediate container a048649835ad
[15:54:47] ---> 41ed94ddcb59
```

It's using Teamcity's 'Docker' runner type, and the agent has access to the host machine's docker daemon because start these containers on that.

In contrast, a different Dockerfile, based on `openjdk:8-jdk` caches very happily.

The checkout is the same - the directory only contains the dockerfile.

Comment: Hi, could you please share how TeamCity build agent is started?

Comment: The agent itself? It's running inside a dedicated docker container which has access to the docker socket. What particular aspect of how it's started are you after?

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity does not use the docker cache by default. 
You can setup it with Docker build's --cache-from [option](https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/engine/reference/commandline/build/)